# Memory Leak in Windows 10 TNotification in Delphi Seattle?

Tags: delphi, notifications, windows-10, delphi-10-seattle

I'm implementing Windows 10 Notification in my application. However, the code below (which runs fine) apparently give a memo leak of 1 TNotification object and 2 strings, yet I free the object at the end of the block:

```
aNotification := NotificationCenter.CreateNotification;

//-- If not assigned then must be Win 8.1 or below
if not assigned(aNotification) then
  exit;

try
  aNotification.Title := AlignMixVersionName + ' License';
  aNotification.AlertBody := aText;

  NotificationCenter.PresentNotification(aNotification);

finally
  aNotification.Free;
end;
```

Am I doing something stupid or is there a memory leak in the implementation of Notifications?

- Steve

Comment: what is the value of `aNotification` after `NotificationCenter.PresentNotification(aNotification)` ?

Comment: @HughJones `aNotification` is still assigned after `PresentNotification` - so strange.

Comment: I did Delphi many moons ago and remember setting things to nil ... aNotification := nil;

Comment: There was an issue opened for this mem leak in RAD Studio's issue tracker: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-17660

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is indeed a leak caused by `TNotificationCenterDelegateActivated`. In its `Create` a copy of the `TNotification` parameter is created, but never freed.

Seems like some developers responsible for this code are not that proficient with non-ARC environments.

Comment: Thanks for confirming.

Comment: Would be great to QC this at Emba.

Comment: Naively one might expect Emba to have tests for their libraries that would flush out leaks. How hard could it be?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Naively one might expect they have a simple app to test and the very first line of written code is `ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := true;`.

Comment: @UweRaabe - does that mean we have very little hope of a positive result?

Comment: @HughJones, No - merely the opposite.

Comment: @UweRaabe - what does 'ARC' stand for?

Comment: @HughJones, ARC = Automated Reference Counting. It is a new feature of the Delphi mobile compilers. Sometimes features are developed for mobile first and then ported to Win32 and Win64. That is where such errors creep in.

Comment: @UweRaabe - so is it the same as 'Garbage Collection'?  (not to worry - I found this : http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/automatic_reference_counting_for_delphi.html)

Comment: @Hugh No it is different from garbage collection